# Slow MySQL Query "copying to tmp table", help re-writing it

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, url-rewriting

This mysql query is extremely slow, when I look at the query it is "copying to tmp table". These tables are very large especially search_attribute (79 million rows) and search_attribute_values (350,000 rows)

```
SELECT attributenames.name, search_attribute_values.value 
FROM attributenames, categorysearchattributes, search_attribute, search_attribute_values 
WHERE 
categorysearchattributes.attributeid = attributenames.attributeid AND categorysearchattributes.categoryid = 4800 AND
categorysearchattributes.attributeid = search_attribute.attributeid AND 
search_attribute.valueid = search_attribute_values.valueid AND 
attributenames.localeid = 1 
GROUP BY search_attribute.valueid
```

[Here is a picture of the EXPLAIN of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ7Gd.png)

Here is my database schema

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.46, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: 
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;



--
-- Table structure for table `attributenames`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `attributenames`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `attributenames` (
  `attributeid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(110) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `localeid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `attributenames_attributeID` (`attributeid`),
  KEY `attributenames_localeID` (`localeid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;


--
-- Table structure for table `categorysearchattributes`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categorysearchattributes`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `categorysearchattributes` (
  `categoryid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `attributeid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isactive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  KEY `caterysearchattributes_aID` (`attributeid`),
  KEY `caterysearchattributes_cID` (`categoryid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `product`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `product`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `productid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `manufacturerid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isactive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `mfgpartno` varchar(70) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `categoryid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isaccessory` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `equivalency` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `creationdate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `modifieddate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `lastupdated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`productid`),
  KEY `product_manufacturerID` (`manufacturerid`),
  KEY `product_categoryID` (`categoryid`),
  KEY `product_mfgPartNo` (`mfgpartno`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `search_attribute`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `search_attribute`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `search_attribute` (
  `productid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `attributeid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `valueid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `localeid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `setnumber` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isactive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`productid`,`localeid`,`attributeid`,`setnumber`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `search_attribute_values`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `search_attribute_values`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `search_attribute_values` (
  `valueid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `absolutevalue` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `unitid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isabsolute` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`valueid`),
  KEY `search_attrval_value` (`value`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

[Added attributeid_valueid index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1auw.png)

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the EXPLAIN query in the picture, the table `search_attribute` is doing a full table scan i.e. not using indexes at all.

Adding index to `valueid` column of `search_attribute` table should make it faster. Give it a try and share your results after adding index.

```
ALTER TABLE `search_attribute` ADD KEY `idx_valueid` (`valueid`);
```

Please try the combinations of suggestions below.

Comment: You can try adding index as per my post.

Comment: i added that index and its still very slow

Comment: Please post `EXPLAIN` after adding the index.

Comment: added the picture to my original post, see the very bottom of my post

Comment: ok. so now index is catching up but its not using it. `FORCE INDEX` will be helpful do the trick.
`FROM attributenames, categorysearchattributes, search_attribute FORCE INDEX (valueid), search_attribute_values`

Comment: Added the explain in original post

Comment: if in the table `search_attribute`, if you had a composite index on `(attributeid,valueid)`  and you killed the previous index you suggested, and you did not `force index`, this thing has a chance of being snappy

Comment: it really comes down to the `cardinality` of the index if you choose to `force index`, and that index is only on one column. But the OP apparently did not change the query to try what you suggested.

Comment: okay im going to try what drew suggested, takes a while to drop and add indexes

Comment: and another thing, the table we are talking about has a composite index already on like next to all of the columns. You might find that adding valueid to it might not be a bad idea (they are thin columns), and it *may*  benefit other queries in your system. In the end, get rid of any residue indexes you did here that you don't need (as you know). Over and out, thanks for helping him, @Samir

Comment: adding the (attributeid,valueid) composite index as we speak

Comment: added the index and executed the query in about 23 seconds. see the explain in original post. can we get it faster than that? like under a second?

Comment: @Drew, your suggestion of adding composite key is awesome :). Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome Samir. I wouldn't leave ya hangin, after torturing you before :P

Comment: I've modified the original query and posted a new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084531/slow-mysql-query-performance