# Slow mysql query, copying to tmp table, using filesort

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I need to speed up this query. It takes 12 seconds, returns 3917 records. My installation of mySQL is not tuned for performance, maybe I need to modify some configuration variables to help performance. The query says "**Copying to tmp table**" for most of the duration of the query.

This query is used to generate the filters for parametric searching (ie. filtering search results by brand name, color, etc).

Query:

```
SELECT  attributenames.attributeid,
        search_attribute_values.valueid,
        attributenames.name,
        search_attribute_values.value,
        count(search_attribute_values.value) as count,
        search_attribute_values.absolutevalue
    FROM  product
    INNER JOIN  vendorimport
               ON (vendorimport.productid = product.productid
              AND  product.categoryid = 4871)
    INNER JOIN  search_attribute
               ON (search_attribute.productid = product.productid
              AND  search_attribute.localeid = 1)
    INNER JOIN  search_attribute_values
               ON (search_attribute.valueid = search_attribute_values.valueid)
    INNER JOIN  attributenames
               ON (attributenames.attributeid = search_attribute.attributeid
              AND  attributenames.localeid = 1)
    GROUP BY  attributenames.attributeid, search_attribute_values.valueid
```

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                   | type   | possible_keys                                      | key                        | key_len | ref                                   | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | product                 | ref    | PRIMARY,product_categoryID,categoryid_productid    | categoryid_productid       | 4       | const                                 | 38729 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vendorimport            | ref    | productimport_productid                            | productimport_productid    | 5       | microcad.product.productid            |     1 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | search_attribute        | ref    | PRIMARY                                            | PRIMARY                    | 8       | microcad.vendorimport.productid,const |     8 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | attributenames          | ref    | attributenames_attributeID,attributenames_localeID | attributenames_attributeID | 8       | microcad.search_attribute.attributeid |     4 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | search_attribute_values | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                            | PRIMARY                    | 4       | microcad.search_attribute.valueid     |     1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Schema:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `attributenames`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `attributenames`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `attributenames` (
  `attributeid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(110) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `localeid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `attributenames_attributeID` (`attributeid`),
  KEY `attributenames_localeID` (`localeid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `product`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `product`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `productid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `manufacturerid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isactive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `mfgpartno` varchar(70) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `categoryid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isaccessory` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `equivalency` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `creationdate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `modifieddate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `lastupdated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`productid`),
  KEY `product_manufacturerID` (`manufacturerid`),
  KEY `product_categoryID` (`categoryid`),
  KEY `product_mfgPartNo` (`mfgpartno`),
  KEY `categoryid_productid` (`categoryid_productid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `search_attribute`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `search_attribute`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `search_attribute` (
  `productid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `attributeid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `valueid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `localeid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `setnumber` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isactive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`productid`,`localeid`,`attributeid`,`setnumber`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Table structure for table `search_attribute_values`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `search_attribute_values`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `search_attribute_values` (
  `valueid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `absolutevalue` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `unitid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isabsolute` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`valueid`),
  KEY `search_attrval_value` (`value`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Number of Records in each table:

search_attribute is 72,000,000, 
search_attribute_values is 350,000, 
product is 4,000,000

[image: Example of search filters]

Comment: For one, I would recommend you get rid of the defaults (especially on the varchar columns) and use NULL.  Also, you should read up on indexes (clustered and non-clustered) and consider using them on columns that are frequently referenced in your queries.  Finally, look at the query plan for your query and see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: I have changed the varchar columns default to NULL. I already have many indexes on the columns that I use frequently. I am interested in speeding up this specific query.

Comment: I would start by creating an index on `category_id, product_id` and run a simple query `select product_id from product where category_id = 4871`. That is the fastest your query will run. Then build from there.

Comment: @JRD I added the index of (categoryid,productid) to the product table, and now the explain is showing 'using index', I already updated the original question to show it. The query is still on the slower side.

Comment: The basic query should be quick with the indexes in place. There is an issue with the GROUP BY clause (ie, you are not grouping on all the non aggregate fields, but while this might give dodgy results I doubt it will have a performance impact). The attributenames table could do with an index covering both attributeid and localeid (ie, one index on both, no 2 indices). Have you tried analyze table to update the stats MySQL uses to decide which index to use?

Comment: I have tried ANALYZE table and it does not help query performance any further. I added the index as per your recommendation to the attributenames table and the query is using it, although its still performing a filesort and copying to tmp table.

Comment: There is no getting around the fact that you have a significant chunk of data to scan through. Starting with the base query on product, what is the incremental time and resulting row counts added for each join? Is it accurate that 38729 rows come back from product before the joins?

Comment: I want to test the query, but I feel like it keeps getting cached, and doesn't show the true performance, can I turn off cache temporarily?

Comment: Use _SELECT SQL_NOCACHE columns FROM tables...._ syntax

Comment: its the GROUP BY that causes the query to become super slow.

Comment: would it help if I reduced the size of the search_attribute table by about 60%?

Comment: Looking at the query again, you GROUP BY attributeid and valueid from 2 different tables, but both the values of those are on the search_attribute table. If you switch to taking the values from search_attribute , and group on the values from search_attribute  then it might be possible for it to take advantage of an index on those fields on the search_attribute  table.

Comment: @Kickstart, I made the change you suggested, and the query feels much quicker - thank you very  much!!

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` vs `NOT NULL` -- Use `NOT NULL` unless you have a business reason for `NULL`.

Use InnoDB with relevant `PRIMARY KEY` on each table.  That will probably be faster.

"Using index", where it makes sense, will help some.

`product.categoryid = 4871` does not belong in the `ON` clause for `vendorimport`; move it to a `WHERE` clause.  (This won't speed things up.)

Your query cannot be optimizer further -- it *must* do all the JOINs and deliver all the rows.

But... Do you really want 3917 rows of output?  Can you deal with that?  Maybe you only want a few of them and could filter them during the SELECT?  That could speed things up.

Comment: The query generates all the products with certain attributes and values, I then use the GROUP BY to generate counts for each value (Microsoft) attribute (Brand Name). 
Example:
Brand Name:
Lenovo (125)
Microsoft (40). I dont know what to do.. I'm just thinking about switching to Apache Solr... but I'd rather get this working faster. I added a picture of the search results, its the filters on the left that are created with this query.